# How to handle licenses when reinstalling ArcGIS 10.1 after computercrash?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, installation, license

In our student organisation we are having some issues with ArcGIS 10.1. When a computer crashes with ArcGIS 10.1 and with a valid student license for one year, is it possible to reinstall it after the crash with the same license number? A lot of our students had some real troubles with it because it says it's already installed on a machine, and the only thing our university gives as an answer is: "just come and swap your license with a new one".

Even in the ArcGIS Support Center I can't find a good solution for this.
Hopefully someone here got a solution for this or know a way-around for the problem, because a lot of valid licenses were already thrown away.

Comment: Have you tried your local Esri support for this one?  It should be a "bread and butter" question for them to provide either a technical or marketing solution.  If you are on some sort of Educational License I am thinking you should have a registered Technical Contact who can raise it as an issue.

Comment: As @PolyGeo says, Esri Customer Service should be able to help you resolve this ([contact info here](http://support.esri.com/phoneSupport#be))From the tone of your message I suspect your name is not on the list of people allowed to contact them, however, do it anyway and you might get bounced to the right place, eventually. In the meantime see if the recipe at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49290/the-simplest-way-to-uninstall-any-and-all-arcgis-products helps get a clean enough slate to allow a reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind this is from my experience with for pay licenses of ArcGIS but I think it operates the same.  On occasions I've had people reinstall their machines or scrap them before they deauthorize licenses (I've been guilty of this) and when I log onto my customer care portal it says that the license is already authorized to someone, you have to tell it to deauthorize the license before you reinstall.  So, when they reinstall the software and then go to authorize it says that the license has already been authorized by another machine.  I normally call our ESRI rep to reset the license, but I've been in a hurry before and the people on the chat tech support were able to reauthorize the license.

When I was still in school they handed those things out like candy and our profs had huge stacks of them in their offices.  It's just an authorization code, but it is a waste of the paper and plastic of the sleeve and disc.

Answer (score 0):

On windows make sure there is nothing left in program files folders that is named either esri or ArcGIS. Also make sure the registry is cleared too. I don't think ArcGIS does a very good job of house keeping when it is uninstalled.  Make sure your IT Dept is involved if you mess with the registry because a wrong move there could mean bad things.