# Removing and uninstalling previous version of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, installation, arcgis-9.3

I want to remove and uninstall ArcGIS Desktop 9.3 and subsequently install version 10.1.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49290/the-simplest-way-to-uninstall-any-and-all-arcgis-products

Comment: Have you tried uninstall via the software media disc?  There should be an option uninstall within the setup.exe or uninstall.exe.

Comment: On your download or install disc you should have the option to uninstall previous versions.

Comment: i downloaded ArcGIS 9.3 not from a C.D nor online i just got the setup of this software from a colleague. now i have deleted each n every thing of previous version but still showing an error to uninstall previous version.

Comment: no i have'nt downloaded it from a CD nor from internet i just got its setup from a friend.

Comment: Please make an effort. Sentences start with capitals, the personal pronoun is I not i. This is a site for professionals.

Comment: Pirated software often doesn't uninstall cleanly, because it is also filled with malware. If you're getting commercial software from "friends", then your machine is likely a zombie in some Russian crime syndicate's army.

Comment: Check out Stuart's post [here](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/21986).

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Windows, you could use the [ArcGIS 10.1 Uninstall Utility for Windows](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/uninstall-guides/101FinalUninstallUtilityGuide.html) which will uninstall ArcGIS 9.3 in preparation for 10.1.

Note that:

> The ArcGIS 10 Uninstall Utility will remove all ArcGIS 9.3 software **except ArcSDE, ArcGIS License Manager, and certain extensions**. ArcGIS 9.3 Beta software will not be removed.

You may need to remove these manually using *Add/Remove Programs* from the **Control Panel.**

Comment: i am using windows 10. I have already removed ArcGIS 9.3 from control panel, but while downloading version 10.1 its showing an error to uninstall prevision version. also tell me how can i download uninstall utility for this.

Comment: @user63207 - Can't comment too much as I only used ArcGIS once but you may need to manually delete the ArcGIS registry entries by running the **regedit** program in Windows and search for ArcGIS. Also delete any folders and restart your computer. The Uninstall Utility comes bundled with the software but I doubt you have it since you have removed 9.3.

Comment: The uninstall utility is part of each media bundle available for download by customers authorized for software download.  If your registry is mangled by install of unauthorized software, you may find it easier to wipe the OS disk and start over (this process may also remove any malware that may have been installed in place of legitimate ArcGIS libraries).

Comment: @Vince - Thanks for adding clarity and some good advice :)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to uninstall all the components manually from your system (without any tools). Perhaps download the Patchfinder application. This downloadable executable will tell you what products and service packs you still have installed. If you get an empty dialog, you don't have any products installed.

http://downloads2.esri.com/Support/downloads/other_/PatchFinder.exe
(this is a direct download link).