# ArcGIS 10.4 Installation Error- Error 1325 is not a valid short file name

Tags: arcgis-desktop, installation, arcgis-10.4

I am planning to do fresh install of ArcGIS 10.4.1 on win 10 machine and i am keep getting same error 1325- is not a valid short name. 
Also i saw the solution in other post ([Avoiding Error 1325 EsriPyFldr not valid short file name when uninstalling ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174197/avoiding-error-1325-esripyfldr-not-valid-short-file-name-when-uninstalling-arcgi))
 suggesting to remove ESRI from below location but  in my registry this not exists HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ESRI so that option is not working for me.

Also I made changes to registry HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders and  I reset the data to %USERPROFILE%\My Pictures but still no luck.

Any other solution to try please?

Comment: I get this when i try to install ArcGIS at work unless i log on windows with an admin account

Comment: I am admin on my local machine as well but still installation is not going through.

Comment: Even as an administrator on your own machine, you may need to right click and 'run as administrator' on the install.

Comment: Sounds like your installing from a folder with a space in it?  try c:/temp/ run as admin.

Comment: Check this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/175007/1315

Comment: Don't forget to take the 2-minute [Tour] that is designed to introduce all users to the site.